# Is it possible to see which percentile I'm in for the given year?

Tags: discussion, support, score

I see on my profile below my reputation score "top x% this month". My questions are:

1) Is it possible to see which specific percentile I'm in? I don't know if they just show "10%" for everyone in the top 10%. So for example, if I'm in the top 9%, would it show "top 9%" or still "top 10%"?

2) Is it possible to see my stats for the given year instead of the month?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @yivi and @RageFoxx for the suggestions. The way to find the percentile you're in is to go to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta, search for your name, find your ranking, click to go to the last page so you can see the total number of users, then do (your ranking / total number of users) x 100%

Comment: That percentile is a link. Have you clicked on that link?

Comment: Yep, I didn't see anything from there that would do what I was looking for though. Do you?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta - That's approximately where the link goes.  Gives the exact position you are in, not the percentile but a little arithmetic should get you there.

Comment: Ok yep, I didn't dig into it enough the first time. Thanks!